# Why doesn't my expander control default to open on page load?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a group header template for a listboxitem that uses an expander bound to a bool IsExpanded property with INotifyPropertyChanged.  The Interaction Trigger was added so that I could expand and collapse all listboxitems in the listbox at once.

My problem is I want the group headers to default to expanded when the control opens (it currently does not).  I thought setting `<Expander IsExpanded="True">` would accomplish this but it doesn't seem to have any impact on the display.  Any thoughts?  Full code snippet below.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                   FontSize="16"
                                   FontWeight="Bold">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
                                    <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ItemCount"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Expander.Content>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>
```

Comment: is `DataContext.IsExpanded` set to true by default.

Comment: It is set to true by default.  Also, an aside, code does not display well in comments...

Comment: Try putting something in your `<Expander.Content>`

Comment: The expander is part of a larger containerstyle with a groupitem as the target.  I fill the content with a listbox item template.  The content appears as designed on run.  The only issue with implementation is that the group header expander is not expanded when I open the control.

Comment: I could not understand the use of interaction trigger here. Seems like you can directly bind IsExpanded of Expander to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.IsExpanded}`. If it still does not work then there is the problem with the binding

Comment: I want to be able to expand each group in the list box individually and also be able to expand all and contract all groups at once.